# Reference needed for limiting word of random walk on free group

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-walk, free-groups

I'm looking for a reference on random walks on free groups that gives some kind of theorem about existence of a limiting word. A specific case I'm interested in is the free group on two letter $a,b$, where $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$ are all chosen with equal probabilities.

That is, we start with the empty word and at each time step multiply by one of the choices and start building up a word, e.g.
$$
aaaba^{-1}bbbab.
$$
By "limiting word" I mean the length of the finite word tends to infinity and hence for each $n$, eventually the $n$th letter of the word becomes constant. The limiting word is then defined to be made of these finalized letters.

In the book of David William *Probability with Martingales* a specific example is given in two exercises (EG.3 and EG.4) but I would like a definitive reference that proves whatever the general version of the theorem I'm talking about is. That is, under what conditions does a limiting word exist?

Comment: This holds under the condition that the random walk is *transient*. In your case, the length of the word is itself a biased random walk on the integers (with positive bias $0.5$) hence the transience is direct.

Comment: @Did Wow such a simple observation. You can post that as an answer and I would accept.